# how to change the font color for dataset value?

Tags: jfreechart

```
CategoryPlot plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, categoryAxis, valueAxis,
                renderer);  
        plot.setOrientation(orientation);   
        plot.setInsets(new RectangleInsets(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0));
        JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(title, JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT,
                plot, legend);
```

How can I change the font color for my dataset? My dataset contains numerical values and I want to make it white while displaying it on the bar chart.

Comment: plot.setRenderer(renderer); use renderer to define the colors.

Comment: Override `getItemPaint()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjfreechart%5d%20GETITEMPAINT).